# Frame upload/creation on H2O external backend hangs from python/pyspark

Tags: pyspark, hadoop-yarn, h2o, sparkling-water

I'm experiencing an issue where the `h2o.H2OFrame([1,2,3])` command is creating a frame within h2o on an *internal backend*, but not on an *external backend*. Instead, the connection is not terminating (the frame is being created but the process hangs).

It would appear that a post to `/3/ParseSetup` is not returning (where `urllib3` seems to get stuck). More specifically, from the h2o logs for a connection to the external backend, an example of this is (where I've shortened the date and IP):

```
* 10.*.*.15:56565 8120 #7003-141 INFO: Reading byte InputStream into Frame:
* 10.*.*.15:56565 8120 #7003-141 INFO: frameKey: upload_8a440dcf457c1e5deacf76a7ac1a4955
* 10.*.*.15:56565 8120 #7003-141 DEBUG: write-lock upload_8a440dcf457c1e5deacf76a7ac1a4955 by job null
* 10.*.*.15:56565 8120 #7003-141 INFO: totalChunks: 1
* 10.*.*.15:56565 8120 #7003-141 INFO: totalBytes:  21
* 10.*.*.15:56565 8120 #7003-141 DEBUG: unlock upload_8a440dcf457c1e5deacf76a7ac1a4955 by job null
* 10.*.*.15:56565 8120 #7003-141 INFO: Success.
* 10.*.*.15:56565 8120 #7003-135 INFO: POST /3/ParseSetup, parms: {source_frames=["upload_8a440dcf457c1e5deacf76a7ac1a4955"], check_header=1, separator=44}
```

By comparison, the internal backend completes that call and the log files contain:

```
** 10.*.*.15:54444 2421 #0581-148 INFO: totalBytes:  21
** 10.*.*.15:54444 2421 #0581-148 INFO: Success.
** 10.*.*.15:54444 2421 #0581-149 INFO: POST /3/ParseSetup, parms: {source_frames=["upload_b985730020211f576ef75143ce0e43f2"], check_header=1, separator=44}
** 10.*.*.15:54444 2421 #0581-150 INFO: POST /3/Parse, parms: {number_columns=1, source_frames=["upload_b985730020211f576ef75143ce0e43f2"], column_types=["Numeric"], single_quotes=False, parse_type=CSV, destination_frame=Key_Frame__upload_b985730020211f576ef75143ce0e43f2.hex, column_names=["C1"], delete_on_done=True, check_header=1, separator=44, blocking=False, chunk_size=4194304}
...
```

There is a difference in the `by job null` lock that occurs, but it is released, so I suspect that it is not a critical issue. I've curled that endpoint unsuccessfully on both backends, and am reviewing the source code to determine why.

I am able to view the uploaded frame running `h2o.ls()`, despite the hanging process, and I'm able to retrieve the frame using `h2o.get_frame(frame_id="myframe_id")` on the external backend.

I've tried/confirmed the following things:

- Confirmed that the sparkling water version is correct with respect to the version of spark (i.e. h2o_pysparkling_2.3 - for Spark 2.3.x, as stated in [docs.h2o.ai](http://docs.h2o.ai/sparkling-water/2.3/latest-stable/doc/pysparkling.html#pysparkling-and-spark-version) --- in my case sparkling water 2.3.12 - Spark 2.3.0.cloudera2);
- Downloaded sparkling-water stable to the cluster and ran `./get-extended-h2o.sh cdh5.14`, which gave me the `h2odriver-sw2.3.0-cdh5.14-extended.jar` jar;
- Various permutations of parameters for the map reduce job. Interestingly, our cluster is quite busy and the base port setting was essential for stability. Also, our sub-nets span switches which messed with the multi-casting. Ultimately the following argument brought up the backend without fail:

```
    hadoop jar h2odriver-sw2.3.0-cdh5.14-extended.jar -Dmapreduce.job.queuename=root.users.myuser -jobname extback -baseport 56565 -nodes 10 -mapperXmx 10g -network 10.*.*.0/24
```

- Confirmed that I could query the backend since `h2o.ls()` works;
- Uploaded a spark dataframe instead of a plain list (same issue):

```
    sdf = session.createDataFrame([
    ('a', 1, 1.0), ('b', 2, 2.0)],
    schema=StructType([StructField("string", StringType()),
                       StructField("int", IntegerType()),
                       StructField("float", FloatType())])) 
    hc.as_h2o_frame(sdf)
```

From a YARN point of view, I attempted client and cluster mode submissions of the simple test app:

```
spark2-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --queue root.users.myuser --conf 'spark.ext.h2o.client.port.base=65656' extreboot.py
```

and without `--master yarn` and `--deploy-mode cluster` for the default client mode.

Lastly, the `extreboot.py` code is:

```
    from pyspark.conf import SparkConf
    from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
    from pysparkling import *
    import h2o

    conf = SparkConf().setAll([
    ('spark.ext.h2o.client.verbose', True),
    ('spark.ext.h2o.client.log.level', 'DEBUG'),
    ('spark.ext.h2o.node.log.level', 'DEBUG'),
    ('spark.ext.h2o.client.port.base', '56565'),
    ('spark.driver.memory','8g'),
    ('spark.ext.h2o.backend.cluster.mode', 'external')])

    session = SparkSession.builder.config(conf=conf).getOrCreate() 

    ip_addr='10.10.10.10'  
    port=56565

    conf = H2OConf(session).set_external_cluster_mode().use_manual_cluster_start().set_h2o_cluster(ip_addr, port).set_cloud_name("extback")
    hc = H2OContext.getOrCreate(session, conf)

    print(h2o.ls())
    h2o.H2OFrame([1,2,3])
    print('DONE')
```

Does anyone know why it may be hanging (in comparison to the internal backend), what I'm doing wrong, or which steps I can take to better debug this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend upgrading to the latest version of Sparkling Water (currently `2.3.26` and available [here](http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/sparkling-water/rel-2.3/26/index.html)), since you are using `2.3.12` and there have been several fixes for hanging issues since then. Hopefully a quick upgrade fixes your issue.